# FPDF If statements in a cell

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

what you will see below is a code that is used to generate reports at the end of the month, the is a button to click to generate report and it is sorted according to month and year.

This file works but I have a problem in the header part this is the code:

```
//Title
$this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
$this->Image('media/logo.png');
$this->Ln(10);
$this->Cell(0,6,'Generated Reports',0,1,'C');
$this->Cell(0,7,'As of Month of ',0,2,'C');
if($date=="01")
{
$pdf->Cell(0,8,'January',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="02")
{
$pdf->Cell(0,8,'February',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="03")
{
$pdf->Cell(0,8,'March',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="04")
{
$pdf->Cell(0,8,'April',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="05")
{
$pdf->Cell(0,8,'May',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="06")
{
$this->Cell(0,8,'June',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="07")
{
$this->Cell(0,8,'July',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="08")
{
$this->Cell(0,8,'August',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="09")
{
$this->Cell(0,8,'September',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="10")
{
$this->Cell(0,8,'October',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="11")
{
$this->Cell(0,8,'November',0,3,'C');
}
else if($date=="12")
{
$this->Cell(0,8,'December',0,3,'C');
}
$this->Ln(10);
//Ensure table header is output
parent::Header();
```

The dates are in numbers so January is 01 Feb = 02 and so on until Dec = 12.

As you can see above i tried using if and even changed `$this` to `$pdf` but still no avail.

It will generate a PDF file but without the month, it will just generate "As of Month of " and the details below it, but not the month in which it was being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use the array to manage of it.

do not mix and miss use of $this(Class member) & $pdf(Class Object)

```
//Title    
$this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
$this->Image('media/logo.png');
$this->Ln(10);
$this->Cell(0,6,'Generated Reports',0,1,'C');

$monthArray = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

$index = intval($date)-1;

$this->Cell(0,7,'As of Month of '.$monthArray[$index],0,2,'C');
$this->Ln(10);
//Ensure table header is output
parent::Header();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is still there. It still wont output the month. I can send you the entire code but it's 23mb file.

Comment: Try and test the `$this->Cell(0,7,'As of Month of '.$date,0,2,'C');`